# In ConTeXt, how to insert one-column chapters abstracts and figures inside two-column text?

Tags: context, columns

I just switched from LaTeX to ConTeXt for a specific document, and I must confess I'm a bit lost with ConTeXt several multi-columns alternatives.

As I understand it, the following code should do the job, but

1. I'm not sure it is correct, even less optimal
2. I'm wondering if there is a way to define globally (i.e. for the whole document) the two-column setting, and then factorize/macro-ize some parts so that abstracts and figures are automatically displayed on one column without extra startcolumns/stopcolumns commands on each occurrence.

---

```
\define[1]\myabstract{\startnarrower[2*middle] #1 \stopnarrower}
\starttext
    \chapter{The first chapter}
    \myabstract{Abstract of the first chapter}
    \startcolumns[n=2]
        This is some random text that fills the first chapter.
        Nothing interesting here.
    \stopcolumns

    \chapter{The second chapter}
    \myabstract{Abstract of the second chapter}
    \startcolumns[n=2]
        This is some random text that fills the second chapter.
    \stopcolumns
    \placefigure.....
    \startcolumns[n=2]
        Nothing interesting here.
    \stopcolumns
\stoptext
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the Wiki:

> There are different possibilities to typeset text in two or more columns:
>
> - columns : for simple cases of multi column text
> - paragraphs : if you need a table-like structure (translations, questionaires etc.)
> - column sets : the flexible way for varying columns or other complex tasks
> - page grids : new column sets implementation (MkIV)
>     streams : set different text synchronized side-by-side (e.g. bilingual editions)

In principle column sets should be the way to go here as they support figures spanning multiple columns, however, their MKIV support is quite poor and personally I cannot recommend using them.

Your example looks okay, but does not fully adhere to “the ConTeXt way”.  Instead of defining your own macros for abstracts you should define your own instance of `narrower`.  The `n=2` option for the columns can be factored out using a global setup.  Always use `\start...\stop` variants of commands.

```
\definenarrower[abstract][2*middle]
\setupcolumns[n=2]

\starttext

\startchapter[title={The first chapter}]
  \startabstract
    \input knuth
  \stopabstract

  \startcolumns
    \input knuth
  \stopcolumns
\stopchapter


\startchapter[title={The second chapter}]
  \startabstract
    \input knuth
  \stopabstract

  \startcolumns
    \input knuth
  \stopcolumns

  \startplacefigure[title=Image]
    \externalfigure[dummy]
  \stopplacefigure

  \startcolumns
    \input knuth
  \stopcolumns
\stopchapter

\stoptext
```